# Dimension Mismatch in LSTM Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I want to create a basic RNN that can add two bytes. Here are the input and outputs, which are expected of a simple addition

```
X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

That is, `X1 = 00101111` and `X2 = 01110010`

```
Y = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I created the following sequential model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(output_dim = 16, input_length = 2, input_dim = 8))
model.add(Activation('relu'`))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

The error I get is something along

> expected `lstm_input_1` to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape `(8L, 2L)`

So if I increase the dimensions by changing X to

```
[[[0 0]] [[1 1]] [[1 1]] [[1 0]] [[0 0]] [[1 0]] [[0 1]] [[1 0]]]
```

Then the error changes to

> expected `lstm_input_1` to have shape `(None, 8, 2)` but got array with shape `(8L, 1L, 2L)`

Answer (score 3):

In Keras the Sequential models expect an input of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, input_dimension)`. I suspect you need to change the two last dimensions of your input array. Remember, the batch dimension is not explicitly defined.

Answer (score 3):

Change X to `[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]]` so that its shape is `(1, 8, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Keras as input requiers 3D data, as stated in error. It is samples, time steps, features. Since you have (8L, 2L) Keras takes it as 2D - [samples, features]. In order to fix it, do something like this

```
def reshape_dataset(train):
    trainX = numpy.reshape(train, (train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[1]))
    return numpy.array(trainX)

x = reshape_dataset(your_dataset)
```

now `X` should be `8L,1,2L` which is [samples, time steps, features] - 3D